# Swift - Button in TableView Crashing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, compiler-errors, uibutton

Okay I have an iOS app in Swift. I have a custom tableview and in my cell I have a button (2 buttons but in fixing one, I can fix the other). When the button is clicked, the cell is supposed to move from one array to another array, but my problem here is when I click the button the app crashes saying unrecognized selector. Any help?

**Error:**

```
CustomCellSwift[4834:1676038] -[CustomCellSwift.ViewController followButtonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b0b490
```

**Follow Button Code:**

```
// Follow Button
@IBAction func followButtonClick(sender: UIButton!) {

    // Adding row to tag
    let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
    if let indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {

        // Showing Status Labels
        let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

        // Change Follow to Following
        (sender as UIButton).setImage(UIImage(named: "follow.png")!, for: .normal)
        cell.followButton.isHidden = true
        cell.followedButton.isHidden = false
        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

        // ----- Inserting Cell to Section 0 -----
        followedArray.insert(testArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
        myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

        // ----- Removing Cell from Section 1 -----
        testArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        let rowToRemove = indexPath.row
        self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .fade)

        self.myTableView.endUpdates()

    }
}
```

**Populate Cell Code**

```
func populateCell(_ testObject: Test, isFollowed: Bool, indexPath: IndexPath, parentView: Any) {

    // Loading Background Color
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    // Loading Images -SDWebImage- *Crashes*
    //let imgURL = (testObject.value(forKey: "testURL") as! String) // as! NSURL
    //self.myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    //self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: imgURL as URL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "no-image.png")) // Missing RefreshCached

    // Loading Status Labels
    self.firstStatusLabel.text = testObject.testStatus1
    self.secondStatusLabel.text = testObject.testStatus2
    self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = true
    self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = true

    if isFollowed {
        self.followedButton.tag = indexPath.row
        self.followedButton.addTarget(parentView, action: Selector(("followedButtonClick:")), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.followedButton.isHidden = false
        self.followButton.isHidden = true

        // Status Labels
        self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
        self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

    }
    else {
        self.followButton.tag = indexPath.row
        self.followButton.addTarget(parentView, action: Selector(("followButtonClick:")), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.followedButton.isHidden = true
        self.followButton.isHidden = false

        // Status Labels
        self.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false // True when done testing
        self.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false // True when done testing

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put a button in a table view cell. Can't you use func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) to react to a table cell being selected and then move to a new array?

Comment: Check if you have connection to action `followButtonClick ` in pinEditor or  in code if you add target.

Comment: @MacUserT I can't, thats not how the design is

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the section number and row number are correct, it will crash too if  position not found into array.

You are using this array

1.followedArray

2.testArray

Please check element are properly added and deleted after inserting cell or deleting cell

Comment: Everything was working fine in Objective-C but then I converted to Swift and now it doesnt work

Comment: Please correct syntax to add action to button in swift 3.0 in your code
add action like below code, myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myClass.pressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Comment: Since I'm new to iOS, whats the difference in this code?

Comment: In swift language you have to add button action with this way  #selector(your faction name)